# Interpretation of absurdly large (but probably correct) Bayes Factors?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, jags

I estimated a Bayes factor to compare a hypothetical model against a null-model (which obviously by visual comparison of the posterior predictive with the data) fails to capture a certain aspect in the data. The sampling is rather rigid. I need to finely tune pseudo priors, use a bisection technique to home in on a prior for the model index which leads to roughly equal samples in both models and thin a lot to obtain an effective sample size of 13000 samples for the model index.

Depending on the data, the Bayes factor against the null-model gets as large as 10^10 or 10^12.

I'm now concerned whether there may be something wrong with Bayes factors this large, or is it just a sign that the comparison isn't very reasonable, since the null-model obviously fails on the data?

Any comments are highly welcome!

P.S: Some details:
The models are advanced psychometric functions (that resemble logistic functions, but are conceptually a bit different, so logit analysis won't help). I have models for two competing hypothesis. The null-model is a special case of each hypothetical model. So I first wanted to calculate BFs for each model against the null.

Answer (score 1):

Let's recall the Bayes factor: $B = \frac{p(d|M_1)}{p(d|M_0)}$, the ratio of model likelihoods $p(d|M_i)$ with data pairs $d = (x,y)$.
These are obtained by marginalising over the respective hyperparameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_0$:

$p(d|M_i) = \int p(d|Mi,\theta_i) p(M_i|\theta_i) d\theta_i$

A very handwavy argument: regions of the model space that don't explain well the data correspond to very low likelihood; in particular, being the null model at the denominator, this might explain the large ratios you see.
Do you further average out over datasets, to obtain a single scalar as Bayes factor? And perhaps you could tell us a little more about the problem at hand?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I first tried to obtain a single BF for four datasets I have (with priors / pseudo priors for each dataset). But the chains were not mixing at all, so I can only obtain BFs for each dataset individually (by properly adjusting the model index priors for each dataset to facilitate sampling the weak model). I was hoping I can average the BFs (or at least draw conclusions if the BFs are large for all sets). I'll add some problem details to the original questions.